# IE8 factory throwing "unknown provider" error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-8

Once again IE8 makes everything difficult.

I have 3 factory [methods?] declared on my angular app. I then have a controller declared. Then I inject the necessary providers for the controller. Looks like this:

```
angular.module('app', ['ui', 'shared', 'visitDirectives', 'GlobalFilters', 'ng']).factory('routingScopeManager', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    var masterScopeTracker = {};
    ....
    return masterScopeTracker;
}]).factory('validationManager', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    var validationTracker = {};
    ...
    return validationTracker;
}]).factory('userManager', ['$http', '$rootScope', '$window', function ($http, $rootScope, $window) {
    var CurrentUser = {};
    ...
    return CurrentUser;
}]);


function visitController($scope, $location, $http, $window, masterScopeTracker, CurrentUser) {
    ...
}


visitController.$inject = ['$scope', '$location', '$http', '$window', 'routingScopeManager', 'userManager'];
```

Everything works dandy in Chrome and Firefox. However IE8 throws this error: Error: Unknown provider: routingScopeManagerProvider <- routingScopeManagerundefined

My applications master page defined ng-app in the HTML tag as follows:

```
<html class="ng-app" ng-app="app">
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here. I've done this in other projects without any issues (when testing with IE8) so I must be overlooking a step. I have followed the guide on the angularjs site to get things to work with IE. Hasn't changed anything. Any direction would be great.

Comment: Having same problems now. Did you find the solution?

Comment: @gorpacrate yes! Notice: <html class="ng-app" ng-app="app">. I have 2 ng-app declaration on the html element. I forgot all about this question. make sure you aren't declaring ng-app more than once on your page!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this was the following:

```
<html class="ng-app" ng-app="app">
```

Here I have 2 ng-app declarations. A simple overlook when I was making this ie8 compatible (using class). You can only have one ng-app declaration or you're going to have a bad time.

fixed:

```
<html class="ng-app">
or
<html ng-app="app">
```